# Converting a series of data with the following format JD:HH:MM:SS:SSSSSS to Julian day.Fractional secs of the day in python

Tags: python, datetime, time, julian-date

I have some time data that I need to modify in order to convert it into Julian day. fractional seconds of the day (i.e. 270.79514 = 9 Sep 2022 7:05). The format for the time I am converting is Julian day:hh:mm:ss:ffff(microseconds) and I need this in UTC time or I need to remove the Julian day piece to do the conversion. All in python.

```
time = 234:16:54:01:695230
```

output I am looking for = `234.62085295`

Is there a method using datetime function to make the change or do I have to remove the Julian day portion first before I can use the time piece to get the fractional seconds of the day?

Comment: the comments suggest you're using pandas, if so, you should clarify this in the question and set the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand you very well but maybe this can help you.

```
date = '234:16:54:01:695230'
days,hours,minutes,seconds,micsec = map(lambda x:int(x),date.split(':'))
fractional = days+(hours+(minutes+(seconds+(micsec/1000000))/60)/60)/24
```

Comment: How do you use the .split with a series? days,hours,minutes,seconds,micsec = map(lambda x:int(x),date.split(':')) results in an error because 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'.

Comment: @Tiggy put Josephdavid07's code in a function, e.g. `to_fractional`, then simply apply to the series like `pd.Series.apply(to_fractional)`.